# Change Linux Host information using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

Is there any Nodejs library or module that I can change Ubuntu host settings like hostname, network things, disk management, etc.? My requirement is to use Nodejs to change the Ubuntu Host's things.